# go to specific post/comment/profile after click push notifications in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have tried many code in my didReceiveRemoteNotification function in appdelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler { 
     //Code
}
```

but didn`t work as expected.

1. With this code, doesn`t navigate to my profile view controller after I click the notification:

   ```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   ProfileViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileIdentifier"];
   controller.userID = @"123";
   controller.userName = @"calvinsug";
   UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
   ```
2. I have tried this also but didn`t navigate to the profile controller

   ```
   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
   ```
3. Finally, I try this code, but it is weird because it doesn't have back button (I think the cause is the profile controller become the initial view).

   ```
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] 
   initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];    
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   ProfileViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileIdentifier"];
   controller.userID = @"123";
   controller.userName = @"calvinsug";
   self.window.rootViewController = controller;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   ```

Any one have solution?

edit: 
I think we can not set our target View controller to become a Root View Controller, because when we click notifications in other apps, we go to main screen first, then go to the specific view controller immediately

Comment: Do you want to change you view controller when your app is running or when app is in background or user is not using you app?

Comment: i want to change my view controller immediately after user click the push notifications when app is  in background

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ProfileViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileIdentifier"];

controller.userID = @"123";

controller.userName = @"calvinsug";
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

`

Comment: it works, but it doesnt have back button, it doesnt have the navigation bar also